# How do I add wrap specific elements in HTML string with a link

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML feed coming into a site and we are replacing certain parts to suit the site. We have the following:

```
$contents = str_replace('<div id="bic-return">', '<a href="http://www.example.com/enquiry/" class="enquire-link">MAKE AN ENQUIRY</a><div id="bic-return">', $contents);
```

And on the page we have the dynamic code that generates something like this:

```
<div id="bic-title">
    2012 Ford Fiesta <span class="main-price">10000</span>
</div>
```

What can we add to the `str_replace` to make the URL `http://www.example.com/enquiry/&vehicle=2012 Ford Fiesta` so we can pass it to a form?

Comment: Depends on what comes in the variable $contents and how it was structured

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is your problem that you are facing in this code? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

First of using str_replace for DOM manipulation is not good.

Secondly, if you are new (which I can sense you are) you will probably look into using `preg_replace` with eval modifiers, which is also not good.

For DOM manipulations like this, you should really use something like DOMDocument+XPath or other DOM implementation.

To give you an example of this done, with your input. It would look like this:

```
<?php
// Your feed source
$html_source = '<div id="bic-title">    2012 Ford Fiesta <span class="main-price">10000</span></div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();

// Put your feed into the DOM.
//  LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD ensures that you don't have <html> and <body> tags in output. PHP Wierdness.
$dom->loadHTML($html_source, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

// Find your element
$div = $dom->getElementById('bic-title');
$div_text = trim($div->nodeValue);

// Make a new link element
$link = $dom->createElement('a');

// Assign the URL you want
$link->setAttribute('href','somelink.php?id=' . urlencode($div_text));

// Move elements from div to link
while($div->childNodes->length > 0){
  $node = $div->childNodes->item(0);
  $div->removeChild($node);
  $link->appendChild($node);
}

// Add link to div
$div->appendChild($link);

// Output
echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

results in:

```
<div id="bic-title"><a href="somelink.php?id=2012+Ford+Fiesta+10000">    2012 Ford Fiesta <span class="main-price">10000</span></a></div>
```